# Html base tag with node.js server

Tags: html, node.js

I am running an app which has

```
<base href="/pos/">
```

so every relative path is mapped to pos. I am running httpster simple server in node.js can anyone tell me how can I configure it to run with this /pos/ or how can it be done in node...

Comment: What is your code/configuration so far?

Comment: So far I have grunt running creating directory called webapp and inside I have all my files. And I just run httpster in the directory but other use IIS to run it and they use /pos/

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would try if all your files are in "pos"

```
mkdir start
mv pos start/
cd start
httpster
```

then load http://127.0.0.1:3333/pos/